# Understanding docker stats cpu utilization

Tags: docker

When I do `docker stats` I see that usage is greater than 100% most of the times. I have a machine which has 8 cores. So, does below output mean that 100% CPU means one core is totally occupied. So, 690% means close to 7 cores is totally occupied ?

```
d99e067cfffc        690.00%             5.517 GiB / 12.7 GiB    43.46%              1.47 GB / 1.03 GB   9.15 MB / 0 B       338
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly as you stated. You can have up to N * 100% CPU usage when N is the number of cores you have.

By the way, you can run the container with a `--cpus <your_num>` flag to limit the usage of CPU cores if you like.
More details in the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources).